# Jquery ajax json get call delivered by Flask web framework - call fails

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsonp, flask

I am trying to have a simple jquery ajax call fetching json data. However, the call fails and I cannot understand very well why.

The code is below. To me it seems all right.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function onDataReceived (data){
        alert('test');
    };

    $("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "/test",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: onDataReceived
        }); 
    });
});
```

EDIT Flask use

The problem here was that I was using Flask and returning a json object. However, returning a pure json creates a cross domain conflict once you try to do the ajax call with jquery. Thus, much easier if you output jsonp from the flask view. To do that, you can use the snippet below (from here: http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/79/). For the javascript piece you can refer to the one above, I only changed dataType from json to jsonp.

```
import json
from functools import wraps
from flask import redirect, request, current_app

def support_jsonp(f): 
"""Wraps JSONified output for JSONP"""
@wraps(f)
 def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
  callback = request.args.get('callback', False)
  if callback:
   content = str(callback) + '(' + str(f().data) + ')'
   return current_app.response_class(content, mimetype='application/json')
  else:
   return f(*args, **kwargs)
  return decorated_function

# then in your view
@default.route('/test', methods=['GET'])
@support_jsonp
def test():
 return jsonify({"foo":"bar"})
```

I am not sure if there is a way to use straight json from flask, there probably is. However, as jsonp is also safer, I think better going with this anyway.

Comment: [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)?

Comment: This is a cross domain issue. Need to use CORS or JSONP for cross domain url's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work because the remote script returns JSON, not JSONP. In order to be able to perform a cross domain AJAX call the remote server need to support either CORS or JSONP. Contact the author of the remote API that you are trying to consume, or read the documentation to understand if it does support it.

The fact that you specified `dataType: "jsonp"` in your request makes jQuery send a `callback` query string parameter to the remote domain expecting it to wrap the response in it. If it doesn't, either the remote domain doesn't support JSONP or maybe the callback parameter is called differently.